# Run the same mapping file for each node in a cluster?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have two dedicated machines for ES (2.2.0). The two machines have the same specs.Regarding ES, I plan to have TWO nodes on each machine for the cluster.

In my development environment (laptop, Windows), I ran

```
curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/elastic-d @my-mapping.json
```

to create the index and mapping.

In the clustered multi-node environment, do I need to run the above command against each node?

Comment: If I understand your question, no, it's once per cluster.

Comment: No just against a single node, the master will make sure the index is created on all nodes.

Comment: mpez0 and Val, thanks for your info. If either of you make it the answer post, I will select it. Again, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you only need to run this command against a single node.

The master node will make sure the index is created on all nodes.